# Automatically resolving BibTeX case mismatch errors

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

Unfortunately, my BibTeX file has been processed by a program that changed all the keys to lowercase. Now my TeX has a mixture of uppercase and lowercase keys. If I cite something once with `\citep{CASE}` and later with `\citep{case}`, BibTeX throws the error: BibTeX Case mismatch error between cite keys CASE and case.

Can I redefine `citep`, `citet`, and `citealt` to first cast everything to lowercase before calling it, so that either uppercase or lowercase will work?

Comment: While it is probably possible it would be imho better to correct the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I redefine `\citep`, `\citet`, and `\citealt` to first cast everything to lowercase ... ?

If this has to be done, it's probably best to take a pre-processor approach. Why? `natbib`'s citation macros (`\citet`, `\citep`, `\citealt`, etc.) can take either one or two *optional* arguments. Modifying the behavior of such macros could be error-prone.

In a pre-processor approach, the *arguments* of all `\cite`-type macros would be converted to all-lowercase letters on the fly, *before* TeX starts its usual work. This approach is feasible if one uses LuaLaTeX and sets up a suitable Lua function that's assigned to the `process_input_buffer` callback. (This callback operates at a very early stage, i.e., as a pre-processor.) The following example code implements this idea.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

%% Create a bib file with two sample entries
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@misc{aa:3001,
  author = "Anne Author",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  year   = 3001,
}
@misc{aazz:3002,
  author = "Anne Author and Zelda Zwicky",
  title  = "Further Thoughts",
  year   = 3002,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
-- The function 'lowercase_cite' does the heavy lifting:
function lowercase_cite ( s )
   return ( s:gsub ( "(\\[cC]ite.-)(%b{})" , 
            function (a,b)  return (a..string.lower(b)) end ) )
end
\end{luacode}

%% Assign 'lowercase_cite' to LuaTeX's 'process_input_buffer' callback
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback (
   "process_input_buffer" , lowercase_cite , "lowercase_cite" )}}

%% Load 'natbib' package and select a suitable bibliography style
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\citet {aa:3001}; \citep{aazz:3002}

\cite {Aa:3001}; \citep {aAZz:3002}

\citealt {AA:3001}; \citealp{AazZ:3002}

\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```